# Can anyone suggest a good framework for automation using Selenium, C# and NUnit 3.0 framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm a beginner in selenium automation and need to implement this in my new project with C# and NUnit3.0. I have designed a framework but that seems a bit buggy so i need a help from this forum.

Comment: This question is too broad and may fetch a lot of answers primarily based on opinion. But, Refer this link if it helps somewhat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602801/which-design-patterns-should-we-use-with-selenium-webdriver/35603886#35603886

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use page object model. It is highly flexible and maintainable. Most of the industries is using page object model for their automation stuff

Few reference to know about page object model:-
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html

Few reference for Page object model in C#:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1013318/Page-Object-Design-Pattern

http://automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks Shubham, actually i have designed the POM model but the problem is that I'm not able to use the same webdriver throughout all test classes. I know the question is very huge in itself only but i thought i can get a proper reference of POM where I can find a clue to re use the same web driver instance in all my test classes.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for accepting the answer. I don't know more about c# .. there is some link which might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100961/how-to-pass-the-same-driver-instance-in-page-object-model

Comment: for c# http://relevantcodes.com/pageobjects-and-pagefactory-design-patterns-in-selenium/

Comment: Thanks Shubham. I must check that.